# How to use Progress parameter in AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to use AFNetworking 2.0 with NSURLSession. I am using the method

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                         fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                         progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress
                                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

How am I supposed to use the progress parameter. The method is a non blocking method. Hence I will have to listen to the '`progress`' to get the updates. But the parameter wouldn't take a property. Only takes a local variable(NSProgress * **__autoreleasing** *). I can't add KVO to a local var.

I am not really sure how to use.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Any time an argument is given as `**` it means that you're supposed to pass in the pointer to the pointer to an existing object, not a pointer to the actual object as you would normally do.

In this case, you pass in a pointer to a pointer to an `NSProgress` object and then observe the changes in that object in order to get the updates.

Example:

```
// Create a progress object and pass it in
NSProgress *progress;
[sessionManager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileURL progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    // Completion code
}];

// Observe fractionCompleted using KVO
[progress addObserver:self
          forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
             context:NULL];
```

Then it gets reported in:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fractionCompleted"] && [object isKindOfClass:[NSProgress class]]) {
        NSProgress *progress = (NSProgress *)object;
        NSLog(@"Progress is %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Being nitpicky it's *a pointer to the pointer* instead of a *pointer*. The actual object lives on the heap. +1 for the correct answer though :)

Comment: @iWasRobbed, I know we have to use the progress like we do for NSError in most of the methods. The problem was I try to listen to progress from a view class where is the upload is happening in a upload manager sort. I do have the manager object in my view. How do I listen to the progress if it is a local (progress) var.

Comment: @Vignesh If this answered your question, please consider closing out the question by hitting the checkmark

Comment: If you add the call to the [super observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject: change:context:], this will cause an error like "message was received but not handled".

Comment: Can someone explain the memory allocations going on here? I see `*progress = delegate.progress;` in `AFURLSessionManager` where `progress` is kept strongly by `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate`. So, is `AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate` keeping the local variable alive?