# Show percentage of a file while downloading by AFNetworking

Tags: ios, download, afnetworking

I can download any file by using the code below (I got it from the Github AFNetworking tutorial page). My question is, how can I display the percentage of the file downloaded in a label while it is downloading ?

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
    return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[targetPath lastPathComponent]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: You could use the progress parameter - try adapting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438261/how-to-use-progress-parameter-in-afnetworking-2-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) - a progressive download operation for AFNetworking

Comment: found a better example here http://code4app.net/ios/AFResumingDownload/505d14116803facd09000000