# AFURLConnectionOperation stops calling downloadProgressBlock after second download is started

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking, and I have an AFURLConnectionOperation to download a file - something like this:

```
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead,long long totalBytesRead,long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    // Update progress stuff
}];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Do completion stuff
}];
[operation start];
```

This code is wrapped in a method, and works perfectly.... until I try to download a second file.

At this point, the `downloadProgressBlock` for the first operation stops being called at all. **However**, the first download still continues, and the `completionBlock` is called at the very end - just without any progress updates.

I think it may be something to do with retaining/ARC/whatever else but honestly I have no idea - it doesn't make sense to me. Everything works perfectly until a second download is started despite the fact that the methods are called separately and the `operation` variables and progress blocks don't rely on each other, reference each other or do absolutely anything related to each other!

**EDIT:** I have not found the cause/solution to *this* problem, but I have found and posted a workaround using a different AFNetworking method to download files. If anyone can resolve the original problem, please post an answer and I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never resolved this problem but I've found a workaround. The example code in the question was from the wiki on an earlier version of AFNetworking. I have checked again and it seems that now they have updated their suggested methods to download files, so I'm now using this code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSProgress *progress;

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Combine with [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19440422/400966) to observe the `NSProgress` updates. This works perfectly and achieves the behaviour that I wanted, though it's a tiny bit more complicated.