# using a strong NSProgress with downloadtaskwithrequest

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking-2

I'm facing a strong vs. autorelease problem :

I'm using an object which have a strong NSProgress to manage some file download.
For downloading, i'm using `downloadtaskwithrequest` from AFNetworking. 
My problem is that this method take a `NSProgress * __autoreleasing *` which is not compatible with my strong NSProgress :

This is my object owning its NSProgress :

```
@interface MyDocument ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSProgress *progress;
@end

@implementation MyDocument ()
-(void)download
{
    [myApiClient downloadFileWithUrl:_url progress:_progress]
}
@end
```

This is the SessionManager dealing with the download :

```
-(void)downloadFileFromUrl:(NSString*)url progress:(NSProgress * __strong *)progress
{
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self downloadTaskWithRequest:request 
        progress:progress 
        destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
        { ... }
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)
        { ... }];
}
```

This is the error concerning the line `progress:progress` :

```
Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `downloadTaskWithRequest` who initialize the NSProgress object, so I cannot give it directly a NSProgress which is property of my object, i had to create another NSProgress object, and to update my property when needed :

```
-(void)downloadFileFromUrl:(NSString*)url progress:(NSProgress * __strong *)progress
{
    NSProgress *localProgress = nil;
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self downloadTaskWithRequest:request 
    progress:localProgress 
    destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
    { ... }
    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)
    { ... }];

    // Update my property here :
    *progress = localProgress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the pointer to NSProgress object instead of passing object as parameter.
** means you have to pass the pointer to the pointer to an existing object.

```
[myApiClient downloadFileWithUrl:_url progress:&_progress];
```

[You can find more details from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438261/how-to-use-progress-parameter-in-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: If this is your required answer mark it as correct. Thanks